# How to get key and value instead of only value when filtering with JMESPath?

Tags: python, json, jmespath

Input data:

```py
s = {'111': {'name': 'john', 'exp': '1'}, '222': {'name': 'mia', 'exp': '1'}}
```

Code:

```py
import jmespath
jmespath.search("(*)[?name=='john']", s)
```

Output:

```py
[{'name': 'john', 'exp': '1'}]
```

Output I want:

```py
[{'111': {'name': 'john', 'exp': '1'}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the dictionary to the list

```py
l1 = [{'key': k, 'value': v} for k, v in s.items()]
```

gives

```py
[{'key': '111', 'value': {'name': 'john', 'exp': '1'}}, {'key': '222', 'value': {'name': 'mia', 'exp': '1'}}]
```

Select the values where the attribute *name* is *john*

```py
l2 = jmespath.search('[?value.name == `john`]', l1)
```

gives

```yaml
[{'key': '111', 'value': {'name': 'john', 'exp': '1'}}]
```

Convert the list back to the dictionary

```py
s2 = dict([[i['key'], i['value']] for i in l2])
```

gives the expected result

```py
{'111': {'name': 'john', 'exp': '1'}}
```

---

Example of complete code for testing

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import jmespath


s = {'111': {'name': 'john', 'exp': '1'},
     '222': {'name': 'mia', 'exp': '1'}}
#    '333': {'name': 'john', 'exp': '1'}}
l1 = [{'key': k, 'value': v} for k, v in s.items()]
print(l1)
l2 = jmespath.search('[?value.name == `john`]', l1)
print(l2)
s2 = dict([[i['key'], i['value']] for i in l2])
print(s2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot preserve keys in JMESPath when doing an [object projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#object-projections), and that you will have to resort to a loop to have a JSON structure that will allow you to have your desired output [*<sup>see the other answer</sup>*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75276368/2123530), the best will probably be to let JMESPath aside for your use case and achieve it with a list comprehension:

Given:

```py
s = {
    '111': {'name': 'john', 'exp': '1'}, 
    '222': {'name': 'mia', 'exp': '1'},
}

print([
    {key: value} 
    for key, value in s.items() 
    if value['name'] == 'john'
])
```

This yields the expect:

```py
[{'111': {'name': 'john', 'exp': '1'}}]
```